# I uploaded video to wordpress but cannot check the media file directly on the website

Tags: wordpress, video, directory, media

I am uploading video file to the wordpress post. It's just 7-8 MB's. Its playing perfectly on other websites. When I copy/paste the link from post in the browser. Its now showing me the file. Is it because the directory is protected? or is there any other issue?

[Link to File](https://www.app.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Pindi-Batian-Police-Action-Against-Criminals-1-1.mp4)

The file is there but cannot be viewed directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the videos of your site are hosted on "https://vid.app.com.pk/" so the right URL should be https://vid.app.com.pk/vid/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Pindi-Batian-Police-Action-Against-Criminals-1-1.mp4

Comment: No. Actually, that is a totally different wordpress website.